# Spring Batch Bean Placement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-bean

Does placement of beans make a different when loading them into a scoped context? Is this a bug or a timing of instantiation issue?

If I include the @StepScope and @Bean directly in the BatchConfiguration class, everything works seamlessly with StepScope. However, if I define another class, say "BatchProcessProcessor" as included below, and mark a method within that other class as a Bean with StepScope, it does not resolve properly. The actual symptom in spring batch is StepScope not triggering and the beans being loaded as Singletons.

Something about providing the @Bean and @StepScope from another class that is loaded via constructor injection in the BatchConfiguration does not resolve properly.

Format described above, included below:

Main batch configuration class

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    private BatchProcessProcessor processor;

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        // override to do not set datasource even if a datasource exist.
        // initialize will use a Map based JobRepository (instead of database)
    }

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autwired
    public BatchConfiguration(BatchProcessProcessor processor){
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ListItemReader<String> reader() {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        stringList.add("test");
        stringList.add("another test");
        log.info("LOGGING A BUNCH OF STUFF THIS IS UNIQUE" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        return new ListItemReader<>(stringList);
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public CustomWriter writer() {
        return new CustomWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<String, String> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor.processor())
                .writer(writer()).build();
    }

}
```

Processor container class

```
@Component
public class BatchProcessProcessor {

    private MyService service;

    @Autowired
    BatchProcessProcessor(MyService service){
        this.service= service;
    }

    /**
     * Generate processor utilized for processing
     * @return StringProcessor for testing
     */
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public DeploymentProcesser processor() {
        return new DeploymentProcessor(service);
    }
}
```

Actual Processor

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class DeploymentProcesser implements ItemProcessor<Deployment, Model> {

    private MyService service;

    @Autowired
    public DeploymentProcesser(MyService service){
        this.service= service;
    }

    @Override
    public Model process(final Deployment deployment) {
        log.info(String.format("Processing %s details", deployment.getId()));
        Model model = new Model();
        model.setId(deployment.getId());
        return model;
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, when the BatchConfiguration loads it should inject the BatchProcessProcessor and load the bean with stepscope, but that doesn't seem to work.

As I said before, just copy-pasting the @Bean/@StepScope directly into the BatchConfiguration and returning the same DeploymentProcessor works perfectly and StepScope resolves.

Is this a lifecycle issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not make sense to declare a bean in a class annotated with `@Component`:

```
@Component
public class BatchProcessProcessor {

   private MyService service;

   @Autowired // This is correct, you can autowire collaborators
   public DeploymentProcesser(MyService service){
       this.service= service;
   }

   @Bean // THIS IS NOT CORRECT
   @StepScope
   public DeploymentProcesser processor() {
      return new DeploymentProcessor(service);
   } 
}
```

You should rather do it in a configuration class annotated with `@Configuration`. That's why it works when you do it in `BatchConfiguration`.